# Excel VBA AddConnector method positions screwed up in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

In an Access VBA Application I maintain some VBA-Code which generates an Excel-File on the fly. Recently the user base migrated to Excel 2010.

Since then the following snippet, which creates arrows in the Excel, screws up the positions which worked fine before on Excel 2003:

```
Set ShapeObject = myWorksheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorCurve, X1, Y1, DeltaX, DeltaY)
```

X1 and Y1 are the top and left coordinates of the start of my arrow.

DeltaX and DeltaY are the horizontal and vertical distance of the end of my arrow referring to its start.

The resulting start of my arrow is correct but its end is only correct on machines with Excel 2003. On machines with higher versions of Excel (>= 2007) the end of my arrow is to the upper end of the document.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long road of trial and error and some forum research the solution popped up to me:

The documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221699(v=office.11).aspx provided by Microsoft for the addConnector Method in Excel 2003 was wrong! Basically the 3rd and 4th parameter are not correctly documented. Although these are named EndX and EndY they represent Width and Height. Somehow I assumed this when originally using this method back in Excel 2003.

Now comes the funny part. In Excel 2007 Microsoft changed the addConnector Method and now it totally conforms to the documentation.

This means my code:

```
Set ShapeObject = myWorksheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorCurve, X1, Y1, DeltaX, DeltaY)
```

works in Excel 2003 but in Excel 2007 and above it had to be adjusted to:

```
Set ShapeObject = myWorksheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorCurve, X1, Y1, X1 + DeltaX, Y1 + DeltaY)
```